# How to calculate the spot variance from the TSRV (Two-Scale Realized variance)

Tags: volatility, time-series, high-frequency, variance

If the TSRV is given by:

$$TSRV = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{i=K}^{n} (S_i - S_{i-K})^2 - \frac{\bar{n}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (S_i - S_{i-1})^2 $$

where $\bar{n} = \frac{n - K + 1}{K}$, with $n$ is the number of data points, $K$ is the ticks.

The spot variance on the interval $[t-h,t]$ is given by:

$$\sigma_t^2 = \frac{TSRV_t - TSRV_{t-h}}{h} $$

Let’s say I have $n=10,000$ data points, and I am trying to find $\sigma_t^2$, which is an array at varying times, $t$. Then if the size of $S$ is $n=10,000$, and $K=10$ then we let the TSRV array have size of something like 800.

My python code is below. I am confused with the $n$ in the TSRV. Should $n$ be the number of points up to time $t$, or is it always the number of points up to max time, $n = size(t_{max})$?

Because sometimes I get negative TSRV because the 1st term is bigger than the 2nd, but from what I understand, the variance of $S_i - S_{i-K}$ should always be bigger than $S_i - S_{i-1}$

````python
H = 800 # size of TSRV array

K=10

n = np.size(S)   # S is an array wih size 10,000


time_index = np.linspace(0,n,H+1,dtype=int)
time_index = time_index[1:]  # new time scale for the TSRV

TSRV = np.empty(H)

idx=0
for j in time_index:
    n = n.size(S[K:j])
    n_bar = (n-K+1) / K
    
    TSRV_1 = np.sum((S[K:j]- S[:j-K])**2)
    TSRV_2 = np.sum((S[1:j] - S[:j-1])**2)

    TSRV[idx] = 1/K * TSRV_1 - n_bar / n * TSRV_2

    idx+=1

t=0
idx=0
T = int(H/2)
variance = np.empty(T)

# Here we are choosing h = 2, so TSRV_2 - TSRV_0,  TSRV_4 - TSRV_2,… 
while t < T:
    variance[idx] = (TSRV[2*(t+1)] - TSRV[2*t]) / (time_max/T)
    t+=1

    idx+=1
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Determining $n$ in your simulation procedure:

$n$ is the amount of intraday data between two days $[t-1, t]$. If we assume a 1-second frequency during NYSE time opening hours, we have $n = 60 \cdot 60 \cdot 6.5 = 23400$ points of intraday data (NYSE time is 9:30AM - 4PM, giving us 6.5 hours). Working with data during the opening hours of the market, is *usually* what is preferred empirically for many high-frequency financial papers.

For many simulation procedures concerning realized volatility, whether we gather 23400 data points in the span of 6.5 hours or assume their distribution across a full 24-hour duration does not significantly impact the results. **Most of the time, the goal with the simulation procedure is to investigate the realized estimator in a manner that is independent by the specific intraday sampling period of the data.** This is true if, for example, you want to check whether your realized estimator converges to the "true" volatility of your stochastic process.

**As such, you can let $n=23400$ and assume this is distributed over the entire 24 hour period.**

---

## Negative TSRV estimate:

For brevity, let's define the TSRV estimator as:
\begin{align}
TSRV &= \frac{1}{K} \sum_{i=K}^{n} (S_i - S_{i-K})^2 - \frac{\bar{n}}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (S_i - S_{i-1})^2 \\
&=  RV_t^{subavg} - RV_t^{noisy}.
\end{align}

**The fact that TSRV can give negative estimates is well documented in the literature.**

The estimator is designed to work for very high-frequency noisy data, meaning settings where the raw data are sampled every few seconds in case of typical financial data. If this is not the case, the bias-correction term might overcorrect the volatility, leading to negative estimates.

An exempt from **[Aït-Sahalia, Yacine, and Jean Jacod. *High-frequency financial econometrics (2014)*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9781400850327/html) on pp. 234 - 235, highlights this issue** (I have changed the notation to my own):

> **Remark 7.12** (*Practical considerations*) Estimators such as TSRV are
> designed to work for highly liquid assets. Indeed, the bias correction relies
> on the idea that RV computed with all the high-frequency observations, $RV_t^{noisy}$, consists primarily of noise. But if the full data sample frequency is low to begin with (for example, a stock sampled every minute instead of every second), $RV_t^{noisy}$, will not be entirely noise, and bias correcting as above may overcorrect, including in extreme cases possibly yielding a negative estimator in (7.38). So care must be taken to apply the estimator to settings which are appropriate. [...]

If you are doing a simulation experiment and do not assume any (additive) noise process on your log-prices you are bound to run into the same problem. I would advise you to assume an additive noise process, $v_t$, such that we observe $Y_t = S_t + v_t$ and calculate TSRV estimator on the noisy log-price process, $Y_t$ instead. This might alleviate the problem.

---

**Note that you can correct the TSRV estimator for finite sample bias:**

$$
TSRV^{adjusted}_t = \left(1 - \frac{\bar{n}}{n}\right)^{-1} TSRV,
$$
giving you a slightly better version of the TSRV estimator, especially for "smaller" sample sizes.